What is the number validation if I want the user input should be either 9 digit or 12 digit or 15 digit in laravel?
In Laravel form input validation, how can I check user to force input number of either 9 digit or 12 digit or 15 digit?
following this suggession
I tried required|regex:/^(\d{9}|\d{12}|\d{15})$|unique:users,id_no. it shows error.

When validating using regex it is recommended to use an array to separate validation rules e.g.:
$rules = [
   'myfield' => [ 'required', 'regex:/^(\d{9}|\d{12}|\d{15})$/', 'unique:users,id_no' ]
]

This is because there is a conflict between the | used to separate validation rules and the one used as a regex "OR"

Thanks. But a '/' is needed at the end of regex like 'regex:/^(\d{9}|\d{12}|\d{15})$/'
